# What was the wreck of Grunhill's fleet in Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, thor-marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

In the Age of Ultron, Thor brags that his drink was "aged a thousand years in barrels built from the wreck of Grunhill's fleet.  Not meant for mortal men."  This was during the Stan Lee cameo, at the party at Stark tower.

**Who was Grunhill?  And where, when, how was his fleet wrecked?**

Comment: It's probably Brynhild, not Grunhill. Brynhild (or Brunhild) is fairly prominent in Germanic/Norse mythology, although I'm not familiar with a fleet associated with her.

Comment: FWIW, the spelling in the English subtitles (on iTunes) is “Grunhel’s fleet”.

Answer (score 8):

I could find no information on Grunhill in either Marvel or Norse Mythology. I think it might just be a Norse sounding name the writers came up for that scene without basing it on somebody.

The nearest I could see is [Brunilda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brynhildr) (Brynhildr, Brunhild, Brünnhilde, Brynhild) who was a Valkyrie in Norse mythology and or course [Valkyrie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valkyrie_(Marvel_Comics)) in Marvel comics.

perhaps it was means to be Brunhilda and the spelling/pronunciation got garbled somewhere along the way ending up with that we got on screen.

Another possibility is just Thor showboating and it's just something [Volstagg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volstagg) brewed up in his basement and just wanted to hype is up for the silly mortals.